# Combining image texture and brick texture

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, procedural

I am trying to combine a BRICK TEXTURE and some IMAGE TEXTURE but without a great success.

I would like that stone textures fit perfectly inside each paving slabs.

I found this exercises very challenging, it will be wonderful if anyone can be any advice or explaining how these kind of nodes are working together.

[image]
[image]

the image below is what i am trying to avoid
[image]

Yorkstone T4 642 x 427 Px RGB 250kB
[image]

Yorkstone T5 700 x 396 Px RGB 62kB
[image]

Test 1 made with Gimp
[image]

Comment: Could you show the two source images? What is their size? Are you able to overlap them the way you want in an image editor software?

Comment: Thanks very much i am going to add the 2 picture

Comment: I would like to adapt the stone texture to each slabs because this will be very useful for other different paving pattern. I really want to avoid any other editing software.

Comment: perhaps it's just me but what you want is not clear at all, could you reformulate? Are your trying to avoid repeating patterns?

Comment: Sorry this is what i would like to achieve, please see new image above

Comment: I would like that each texture stone image fits inside a slab made with brick texture.
is it clear???

Comment: yes, it's clear  ;)

Comment: but i think that brick texture isn't still able to provide thi things at time being!!! :(

Comment: Here's a useful thread: https://blenderartists.org/t/cycles-brick-tricks-0-1/685934

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [LazyDodo's Cycles Brick Tricks](https://blenderartists.org/t/cycles-brick-tricks-0-1/685934/1)

In the linked Blender artis thread of the title, Lazy Dodo is presenting a collection of complex nodegroups themed around the procedurale Brick texture. In practice is reconstructing them node by node with the built in function.

In addition to the usual parameters, their nodes outputs provide several useful function, like the UV of each tile present in the **"brick_wall_basic"** nodegroup you can find in the blendfile provided by the author or use the [add-on](https://github.com/LazyDodo/BrickTricks):

[image]

We can easily use this texture to repat a pattern by simply using the UV output as a Texture Coordinate of our images.

Give those two pattern, in order to overlap them, we'll use the original Brick texture Color output as a mask for a nice procedural variation:
[image]

Sincronize the input values between the two procedural textures to ensure a correct overlap between them as long as possible (Brick Texture has no input for the Frequency or the Squash, you'll have to update manually or implement the mask in the nodegrup):

[image]